# iOS Firebase/Firestore - How many reads does an array count for

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have code that reads an array. I'm wondering if this counts as 1 read or does every element in the array get counted as a read (Using Firestore)

```
    var userList = [User]()
    var removeUserListener: ListenerRegistration!

    func addUserObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
        removeUserListener = FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            self.userList.removeAll()
            
            guard error == nil else {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("Error retreiving collection")
                #endif
                return
            }
            
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let email =  document.get("email") as! String
                let username =  document.get("username") as! String
                group.enter()
                if email != Auth.auth().currentUser?.email! {
                    self.userList.append(User(userEmail: email, userID: document.documentID, userName: username))
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
            
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                update()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading one document costs one read operation.  It doesn't matter what that document contains.  Once you have a DocumentSnapshot in memory, all of the fields are free to access as much as you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a beginner. I still don't fully know if I'm getting 1 read or a read for each element in the array?

Comment: An element of an array is not a document. It's part of a document's field.  Once you have a document in memory, you can use all of the fields for free, because it's all already in memory.